# Cannot autowire service "X": argument "$param" of method "__construct()" is type-hi nted "string", you should configure its value explicitly

Tags: symfony, autowired

I have a class with this constructor:

```
    public function __construct(string $username, string $database, string $password, string $host)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->host = $host;
    }
```

In my service configuration file, I have added:

```
App\DataFixtures\Migration\Database\DatabaseConnector:
      arguments:
          $username: '%env(USERNAME_PROD)%'
          $password: '%env(PASSWORD_PROD)%'
          $database: '%env(DATABASE_PROD)%'
          $host: '%env(HOST_PROD)%'
```

I have already try to disable and enable both autoconfigure and autowiring but nothing resolve the issue.

My config file is really loaded.

Comment: Your error message is inconsistent with your posted code.  The error concerns $param while your posted code shows other arguments.  I see you answered by excluding it which is fine as I suspect you are never using the service directly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of autowiring of symfony. When you inject a string as parameter of a service then use autowiring, Symfony doesn't know which string to inject.

You can disable the autowiring the specified service. Be aware that in you services.yaml file, you exclude the service file or folder for autowiring.

For example, in my case, I have added this line:

```
exclude: '../src/DataFixtures/Migration/*'
```